# JavaScript - extract using regex group

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to extract a regex group value pattern of a string?

For example, the following code gives

```
var str = "alpha bravo charlie delta";
var regex = /\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/
var value = str.replace(regex, "$1_$2"); // Gives alphabravo_charlie delta
```

What I am looking for is something like,

```
var value = str.extract(regex, "$1_$2"); // Which should give bravo_charlie
```

While `str.extract` doesn't exist, is there any other way I can get same results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var str = "alpha bravo charlie delta";
var regex = /\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var value = "";
str.replace(regex, function($0, $1, $2){
    value = $1 + "_" + $2;
});

alert(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.match()

```
var array = str.match(regex);
```